# How to format Excel cells selectively by character

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting, visual-basic

I have the following Excel cells:

[image]

What I want to do is to format every cell that contains letters D and E with bold and red colors. How can I achieve that?

In the above example I only format the first two rows by hand.

Overall I have 500 x 40 cells, so I  can't do it manually.

I'm using Microsoft Excel for Mac Version 16.67.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create new Conditional Format

1. Select the range.
2. Home -> Conditional Format -> New Rule -> Use a formula to determine which cells to format. Enter the formula: `=OR(A1="d", A1="e")`.

[image]

3. Click Format, set the font style to `Bold` and the Color to Red. Click OK, click OK.

[image]

4. This will be your result.

[image]

Comment: is there away to format the cell based on *case sensitive* character?

Comment: @littleworth Change the formula to `=OR(EXACT(A1,"D"),EXACT(A1,"E"))`.